# Uninstall Windows 10 Update-1511

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, uninstall, windows-10-v1511

How do you uninstall Windows 10 Update 1511?

After updating Windows 10 to the 1511 update today, none of our users can print labels to our Zebra S4M label printer (S4M00-2001-0100T). This is urgent because all outbound orders and inbound inventory must have labels stuck on them.

Zebra technical support confirmed what I suspected. The 1511 Windows Update broke compatibility with their latest print-driver which worked fine before the update.

You'd think there would be a restore point or something I could restore back to, or an option to uninstall the update. However the latest restore point, I see listed, is for today (after the 1511 update was installed).

And, when I look at a list of recently updates, it only shows updates that were installed today (after the 1511 update was installed).

I've been googling how to uninstall this update, but I haven't found proper instructions.

Short of reinstalling Windows 10, is there a way to go back to the way things were before the 1511 update was installed?

**Edit 1**:

When I click either of these options below, **nothing at all** happens:

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Regarding the issue of the recovery buttons not working, some have reported that rollback doesn't work:
http://wind8apps.com/windows-10-1511-rollback/

Comment: "Go back to an earlier build" should do it. The fact you can't click on the button is weird.  Is this only affecting a single computer? Have you rebooted? Does `SFC` report any problems it can't fix?

Comment: I think I may have uninstalled the cumulative update to 1511, while trying to uninstall 1511 itself. I'll reinstall that, reboot, and see if those buttons start working again.

Comment: None of that worked, and I've confirmed that this same issue (of those buttons not working) exists on other fully updated machines as well.

Comment: Related? http://wind8apps.com/windows-10-1511-rollback/

Comment: Obligatory answer: Restore from a backup. If this machine is critical to your business and you don't have a backup of it, *make instituting a sound backup policy a business priority ASAP*.

Comment: you found the correct way to go back: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/go-back-to-an-earlier-build-of-windows-10 if it doesn't work, your out of luck. Restore a backup. in the Windows Upgrade option you can defer the update to Th2: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-defer-windows-10-updates

Comment: ReimagePlus  is CHOCKFULL OF VIRUSES and MALWARE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Windows 10 1511 update is: automatic, mandatory, and [irreversible](http://wind8apps.com/windows-10-1511-rollback/). Even if you did uninstall it, or some how restored your computer to the state it was in before the update, the same backwards-compatibility-break will just happen again at the time that Microsoft decides to automatically update to 1511 again.

Therefore, my solution to this problem was to install Windows 7 32bit OS onto a workstation that is exclusively dedicated to sharing this label printer. Here's a screen shot of the solution:
[image]

Notice that I did not check the box "Render print jobs on client computers". Surprisingly, the Windows 10 computers (with the 1511 update installed) are able to print to this Zebra Label Printer if Windows 7 is sharing the printer. Perhaps that's due to this render on client option not being checked (not sure because I intuitively unchecked this during the initial setup).

With this solution I can reliable upon the Enterprise Level qualities of Window 7, where updates were optional, avoidable, and reversible (not automatic, mandatory, and [irreversible](http://wind8apps.com/windows-10-1511-rollback/)).

Comment: You're clearly in a business situation, the professional versions allow you to disable updates. Upgrade your VLKs.